# how to get tag value without quotes using js regex

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, tags

How can I get `xxxxxxxxx` value from `value="xxxxxxxxx"`  using RegExp?

Comment: How are you getting the value in the first place? What type of value are you getting, a string, a number, a Boolean? Why, rather than regular expressions, are you not using `HTMLInputElement.value`, or `HTMLElement.getAttribute('value')`?

Comment: Just get the first character in `value`... Such as `^.{1}`. For example: `"xxxxxxxxx".match(/^.{1}/g)` returns `["x"]`.

Comment: value type of string. i get just xxxx

Comment: You want to get the `xxxxxxxxx`?

Comment: yes i want just xxxxx

Comment: So you use a capture group.... but if you are actually matching HTML markup you are going to have issues.

Comment: Okey then. I've added an answer.

Comment: @GunalpAlpUysal Then modify your question, it's very poorly constructed and unclear. It looks like you want just a character `x` inside some string `xxxxxx..`. There isn't even mention that this is an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = 'value="xxxxxxxxx"';

console.log(str.match(/(?![value="])(.+)(?=")/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
var myString = 'value="xxxxxxxxx"';
var myRegexp = /value="(.*)"/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]); // xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getTagValue(htmlStr){
 var pattern=/value="([^"]+)"/g;
 var value=pattern.exec(htmlStr);
 return value[1];
}

var str="<input value=\"xxxxxxxxx\" name=\"test\"/>"
 var result=getTagValue(str);
 document.write(result);
```